# Visual Studio 2015 - Context menu system style

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, designer

When I create a ContextMenuStrip in a Windows Forms Application and set the `RenderMode` to `System`, it looks like this:

[image]

However, the Windows 10 system context menu looks like this:

[image]

How do I make the WinForms Menu look like the actual system one?

Comment: The only difference I see is the highlighting color. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @BastiM Also on Windows 7 there is a small border (see [here](http://i.imgur.com/jn94Vaw.png)). The Visual Studio context menu looks the same on Windows 7. PS: Thanks for editing the question. :)

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you are having a problem with. Can you re-word your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @MattWilko How can he be any more clear? Anyone with this issue knows very well the challenge facing the native context menu style when using "System" property setting in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [`ContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx), not a `ContextMenuStrip`.
Some time ago the `ContextMenu`, which uses native Windows menus got replaced by the `ContextMenuStrip` (that also offers additional functionality).
Straight from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx):

> ContextMenuStrip replaces ContextMenu [...]

I don't have any VS near me at the moment, but I remember the designer will only let you assign a `ContextMenuStrip`. However, you can just set it by code:

```
this.ContextMenu = contextMenu; //preferably in the constructor of the form
```

If I remember this right you have to import the `ContextMenu` into the toolbox first. Right click the Toolbox, Choose Toolbox Items and look for the `ContextMenu` with the namespace `System.Windows.Forms` in the GAC (global assembly cache).